# nested set model (hierarchical data) mysql - concurrent users insert new node in consistency way

Tags: mysql, concurrency, tree, nested

I have read this:
[Transaction safe insertion of node in nested set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128794/transaction-safe-insertion-of-node-in-nested-set)

but I worried about locking of inserting new node in nested set model.
I want insert a new node in my tree categories but I want sure that new node it is inserted without corruption. Engine used in mysql is InnoDb. 
As other question say:

```
 BEGIN; -- or whatever API your framework has for starting a transaction
   SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM myTable WHERE ID = $id FOR UPDATE;  
   UPDATE myTable SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;       
   UPDATE myTable SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;       
   INSERT INTO myTable(title, lft, rgt) VALUES($title, @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);
 COMMIT; -- or whatever API your framework has for commiting a transaction
```

My problem is if concurrent users try to insert new node in same tree, does a transaction is sufficient for update and adjust left and right of others node?
If user1 add new node (execute in transaction1) and at the same time user2 add new node (execute in transaction2), I'm sure that user2 read updated tree with node added by user1 before user2 insert his new node?
So,100 users insert new node in same times last users must wait as long as previews users finish for have always a consistency tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB does row level locking. Thus rows being updated will be locked for the duration of the transaction. This can lead to blocking and deadlocking.

If a row is being updated InnoDB will not be able to acquire a lock on the row to update it again. This effectively serializes the transactions. Note that the transaction isolation level can be controlled see this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynindex-isolevel.html

Also here is a interesting article on how to look for deadlock in a innodb engine http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/.

If the nested sets are being updated heavily making sure you have the right isolation level and wrapping your statement in transaction will be sufficient. However it might create locking, blocking and deadlocking issues that you would need to code for.

Comment: I'm frustrated for locking, blocking and deadlocking, because I can't accept that user wait for long time or locking simulate malfunction service. if I don't lock and use only transaction, tree might corrupted, if I use transaction and also I use lock might block all. Different way or solution? lesser evil?

Comment: Indeed. However I think rather have the user wait a little longer than having a corrupt database that they dont trust.  There is ways to get innodb to run faster. Such as mounting innodb on a seperate raid array for example. This will allow the innodb tables to have dedicated IO. You need to stress test it and then set the users expectations. If you tell a user when 10 million people inserting records at the same time it is going to get slow you might have less complaints.

Comment: Could be more right use SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE? According to doc "SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a shared mode lock on any rows that are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify them until your transaction commits. If any of these rows were changed by another transaction that has not yet committed, your query waits until that transaction ends and then uses the latest values." If user1 add node I can lock row of tree where node is adding and others users can already read data but in same times others can't modify data until transaction in process of user1 is running

Comment: This will certainly help with read speeds . You will need to experiment with the different settings to give you the best performance. Unfortunately there are no right answers for all conditions. You must find the most successful way for your conditions. The nested set is fast for retrieving records you just have to get the write speeds up. Good luck!